# How to defer JQuery click event handling till after Twitter Bootstrap handler has run

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a button-group `.tl` and inside `.tl` I have buttons `label.btn`, when it get clicked, it acts like a checkbox.

Bootstrap made it so when the checkbox is checked, the `label` would gain a `active` class.

**So**, I wanted to run a function when a user clicks on one of the buttons and put all active labels' text into an array.

**But**, the function always returns the last `click` event's result. I tried using `$(".tl").show().delay(100)` but it still **returned all the last active items** into the array. How to fix?

**My problem is my script is running faster than bootstrap even placing the `.active` class**

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group tl">
    <label class="btn active">
        <input type="checkbox" checked> Option 1 Checked
    </label>
    <label class="btn">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 2 Unchecked
    </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".tl").click(function() {
    var returningArray = [];
    $(".tl label.active").each(function () {
        returningArray.push($(this).find("span").text());
    });
});
```

### Example:

```
Action(No.) || initial |   1*  |   2   |   3^  |
------------++---------+-------+-------+-------+
Active Label||  1 2 3  |  2 3  |   3   |  1 3  |
------------++---------+-------+-------+-------+
Array+      ||    X    | 1 2 3 |  2  3 |   3   |

*Clicked button(checkbox) 1 to disable
^Clicked button(checkbox) 1 to enable
+Always returning previous result
```

**P.S. Side question: Also `$(".tl label").click(function() {` didn't work, how to be more precise?**

**P.S. 2: Also, I don't need to necessarily solve the issue above, can suggest any other way to achieve my aim**

Comment: Have you tried mousedown() instead? I had a similar problem and it turns out that the order of checking the element classes is different when you change browser.. Also, have you tried that in a different browser? Try to put an alert before and after to check if the browser checks the value before or after the click event

Comment: Yes, I just corrected the question to `click` so it can be original for my problem.

Comment: could you provide us with a jsfiddle ?

Comment: instead of `$(".tl").click(function() {` try `$(document).on('click', ".tl", function() {`

Comment: is your function wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){...});` ?

Comment: @Dwza yes, my problem is really my code running even faster than bootstrap placing the `.active` class.

Comment: than just check if class was set ^^ `if( $(xy).hasClass('.active'))` else timeout

Comment: @ArunPJohny You were right! Can you read my own answer and place your answer? And can you please explain to me how is this code running?

Comment: which file do you load first.... `bootstrap.js` or `your.js` ?

Comment: @Dwza bootstrap is external, above my own script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is as you suspected the bootstrap method is getting executed after your script...

one messy solution is to bind the handler to the document object so that your handler will get executed after the bootstrap one.

```
$(document).on('click', ".tl", function() {
    var returningArray = [];
    $(".tl label.active").each(function () {
        returningArray.push($(this).find("span").text());
    });
});
```

Comment: does this just delays the execution or queues the execution after bootstrap's code?

Comment: since our handler is registered after bootstrap handler our handler is added after boostrap handler in the event handler queue...

Comment: the correct solution will be is to find out the bootstrap plugin which is used and see whether there is a corresponding change event to handle this case

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, had to answer my own question, bootstrap code is indeed slower than mine.

**But anyone can answer a better one, because I think `setTimeout` isn't good enough.**

### Hacky Fix:

```
$(".tl").click(function() { setTimeout(function() {
    var returningArray = [];
    $(".tl label.active").each(function () {
        returningArray.push($(this).find("span").text());
    }), 100});
});
```